# iPhone 4 camera capabilities to read QR code

Tags: iphone, printing, camera

I have no iPhone 4 here now but I need to know how well is its camera for reading small-size QR codes. Now I have some test QR codes printed on a sheet of paper and my old 1.3MPx smartphone camera doesn't recognize them. So, I wonder how good is iPhone 5MPx camera for doing that. The code I need to be read well from a printed sheet is 16x16mm or so. The size of a single square module is about half of a millimeter now. Please let me know if you have a chance to test it or if you had a deal with such things. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share that image? So we can test and tell you the result with the application we used.

Answer (score 2):

I use the RedLaser app on my iPhone 3GS and it can handle just about every QR code that I've thrown at it. I would venture to say it would work even better with the higher resolution camera and enhanced image processing in the iPhone 4. Good lighting is probably going to be key.

Answer (score 0):

16mmx16mm is pretty small (I tried with with my iPod Touch4G and it didn't work). I would say it would depends on the application which you are using and how well it does the image processing.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I need to make some experiments with this to find out the most compact yet readable size of QR code to use.

Comment: Yea.. Sadly, because of the different cameras that comes with the different iPhones, there won't be one limit which works for all..